# Spring JMS in Wildfly Appserver

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, wildfly-14

I'm using a Spring-Boot-WAR deployed in Wildfly 14 and have implemented a JmsListener which is connected to a Queue. The JmsListener has set the concurrency to 5 and when the Spring-App is starting standalone I see 5 parallel working listeners. But in combination with Wildfly 14, there is only 1 listener running.

In JEE I would annotate the MessageDrivenBean with @Pool and then can configure the max-pool-size for the given pool. But I think the Spring-Listener just connects to the default MDB-Pool which has a size of 1.

Is there a way to connect the JmsListener with a specific bean-instance-pool? Or is there any other way to define an individual max-pool-size for this JmsListener?

standalone.xml

```html
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0">
  ...
  <pools>
    <bean-instance-pools>
      ...
      <strict-max-pool name="individual-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="5" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
    </bean-instance-pools>
  </pools>
```

JmsListener

```java
    @JmsListener(destination = JMS_MESSAGE_NAME, concurrency = "5")
    public void receiveFromMessageQueue(Message msg) {
      ...
    }
```

Comment: As Spring beans are not EJBs there is no way to use the EJB pool of the app server.

Comment: That's completely ok for me. But then the "concurrency" configuration should be used. And i think this also did not happen.

Comment: Two questions: If you are using Spring Boot why do you deploy it to Wildfly? 2) What is JMS_MESSAGE_NAME?

Comment: 1. It is a temporary solution as a movement from monolith to microservices. And it can't be changed so far. :-(
2. JMS_MESSAGE_NAME is just a constant for "MyQueue"

Comment: But then concurrency should simply work. Why do you think that you just have on thread?

Comment: I put 100 Messages to the queue and they just received one after another and not parallel.

Comment: How do you configure the JmsFactory? And which JMS provider are you using?

Comment: Wildfly is using ActiveMQ. And in Spring Boot i didn't configure anything for JMS. Only using EnableJms- and JmsListener-Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In a JEE application server, the JCA specification limits the number of JMS sessions on a JMS connection to one.  In your Spring Boot deployment, you have the 5 concurrent consumers on the JmsListener.  This is achieved by having 5 JMS sessions on the one JMS connection that is managed by the Spring JMS Listener Container.

If you instantiate your own connection factory (not using the Wildfly JCA connection factories), then you can have multiple sessions per connection.